# postgis distance calculation between points with lat, long coordinates

Tags: postgis, convert, distance

Team,

I am new to postgis, but a postgres user for quite a while.  I would like to compare

the geospatial capabilities between postgresql and mongodb.

I have the lat.lon, zip code of US locations;

I ran across this blog entry at http://unserializableone.blogspot.com/2007/02/using-postgis-to-find-points-of.html

Also, I see this the function ST_DWithin

```
SELECT * FROM geotable 
WHERE ST_DWithin(geocolumn, 'POINT(1000 1000)', 100.0);
```

Please advise,

I see that the lat/lon must be converted into points; but I am having issues with the best mechanism to perform indexed distance calculations.

Update..

I have made progress and loaded a spatial aware table .. see below

```
create table public.disttest
(

    zipcode varchar(5),
    state varchar(2),
    city varchar(55),
    long numeric,
    lat numeric

);

SELECT AddGeometryColumn( 'public', 'disttest', 'geom', 32661, 'POINT', 2 );

COPY public.disttest FROM 'c:\temp\zips.txt'

select * from public.disttest limit 10;


UPDATE public.disttest SET geom = ST_Transform(ST_PointFromText('POINT(' || long || ' ' || lat || ')',4269),32661) ;
```

Now the question is how to use the  below type query for a 10 mile radiuus

```
SELECT * FROM public.disttest WHERE ST_DWithin(geom, geom, 16093);
```

Comment: Why have you projected your points to EPSG:32661? why not one of the UTM projection?

Comment: It is all of the US zipcodes. I have retrieved data from this link http://www.census.gov/geo/maps-data/data/gazetteer2010.html GEOID POP10 HU10 ALAND AWATER ALAND_SQMI AWATER_SQMI INTPTLAT INTPTLONG 00601 18570 7744 166659789 799296 64.348 0.309 18.180555 -66.749961 Here is a row of the data. From here, I need to convert tihs lat/long to geometry with respect to an SRID. Please advise, thanks

Comment: This should be a comment to Devdatta's answer.

Comment: yes. for some reason, I could not add a comment to his last reply.  The dynamic gui did not load the button

Comment: You may not have been able to post a comment because you were logged on as a different account. You have two: [christopher smith](http://gis.stackexchange.com/users/17440/christopher-smith) and [Christopher Smith](http://gis.stackexchange.com/users/17473/christopher-smith). Note the different ID numbers in the links. A moderator has since moved the answer to a comment.

Answer (score 1):

As Indicated in my comment, I am not sure why you have chosen EPSG:32661. I would have chosen a UTM projection.

However, the actual usage of the query is quite simple.

[ST_DWithin](http://postgis.refractions.net/documentation/manual-1.4/ST_DWithin.html) requires three inputs. The First two are geometries, and the third is the distance. If you use it in a query, the first geometry comes from your table, and the second geometry is the search geometry.

For example, if you want to search within 10 miles of a point with latitude=y, and longitude =x, the following query can be used

```
SELECT * FROM public.disttest WHERE ST_DWithin(geom, 
                           ST_Transform(ST_MakePoint(x, y),4326),32661), 16093);
```

You need to make sure that the projection of your data, and the projection wkid used in the query are the same.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I am new to the detailed concepts of mapping projecting.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I am new to the detailed concepts of mapping projection.  I humbly request a tad bit more help... If I have a data set of lat,long, when I create the geometry, I need to chose an srid.  Can you walk me through this process?  I ended up getting ERROR:  Input geometry has unknown (0) SRID

********** Error **********

Comment: What is the area of your data? Whole of US? or what?

Comment: It is all of the US zipcodes. I have retrieved data from this link census.gov/geo/maps-data/data/gazetteer2010.html GEOID POP10 HU10 ALAND AWATER ALAND_SQMI AWATER_SQMI INTPTLAT INTPTLONG 00601 18570 7744 166659789 799296 64.348 0.309 18.180555 -66.749961 Here is a row of the data. From here, I need to convert tihs lat/long to geometry with respect to an SRID. Please advise, thanks

Comment: I could try answering this, but I'm not an expert on US projection, so I may give you wrong information . I'll suggest that you post a new question: "Which Projection (with wkid) should I use for the US, to calculate distances?". That way you'll get more authoritative answers.